# Errorless html CSS not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I copied this from a Youtube Tutorial [WATCH HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPh0RbYiYGg) and talked with some people about it and also let both files run through syntax error progs CLLlint and the w3validator. no errors appeared, but the Menu doesn't open/react how it should.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('sidebar-btn').click(function() {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #33676767;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  top: 0;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}

.sidebar.visible {
  left: 0;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li a {
 /* color: white; */
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
}

.sidebar-btn span {
  height: 1px;
  background: #66CC33;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 75%;
}

.sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3) {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sidebar">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/index.html">Sweet</a></li>
    <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/index.html">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="/index.html">4One</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="sidebar-btn">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What should be the expected behavior for this code ?

Comment: The validator reports: **Saw `<` when expecting an attribute name. Probable cause: Missing `>` immediately before.** and several other errors.

Comment: I made a snippet for you and by accident fixed at least one problem with the missing closing script tag

Comment: Ok I fixed 1. the unclosed script tag, 2. the . in the jquery. so far so good, but the sidebar is not opening when I click on it can this maybe caus the trouble?:  `.sidebar.visible
    {
        left:100px;
        transition:left 0.3s linear;
    }` I mean the writing with the second dot .sidebar.visible

Comment: I don't know what made the change, that it finnally worked, but the solution was in finding the original code from the tutorial [here.](https://devdojo.com/episode/create-a-sidebar-menu)

It worked with id's as in the tutorial, as well as when I changed those into classes.

Answer (score 2):

Fix your jquery selector - you are using class instead of ID so do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidebar-btn').click(function(){
       $('.sidebar').toggleClass('visible'); 
    });           
});
```

notice the '.' in front of 'sidebar-btn' that was previously missing - that's a selector for class, notice the '.' instead of '#' in front of the 'sidebar', that's a selector for class whereas '#' was selector for ID

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few problems with that code:

- Your `script` tag isn't closed
- Your `meta` tag isn't closed
- You target the `sidebar` as an ID but it's defined as a class
- Your `sidebar-btn` in jQuery is missing a leading `.` to denote that it's a class

Here is a fixed, working example - the color white is commented out for demo purposes:

```css
 body 
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family:"Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .sidebar
    {
        background: #33676767;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
        position:absolute;
        left: -200px;
        top: 0; 
        transition:left 0.3s linear;
    }

    .sidebar.visible
    {
        left:100px;
        transition:left 0.3s linear;
    }

    ul
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    ul li
    {
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    ul li a
    {
       /* color: white; */
        width: 180px;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .sidebar-btn
    {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 20px;
        height: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 20px;
        position:absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -50px;

    }

    .sidebar-btn span
    {
        height: 1px;
        background: #66CC33;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        display: block;
    }

    .sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2)
    {
        width: 75%;
    }

    .sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3)
    {
        width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/index.html">Sweet</a></li>
        <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/index.html">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="/index.html">4One</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="sidebar-btn">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>

    </div>

</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.sidebar-btn').click(function(){
           $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible'); 
        });           
    });

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: YW - and great you saw the other error before I made a snippet that removed it

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it, but you forgot a . before sidebar-btn, and #sidebar is an id, but in the html it's a class.

try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidebar-btn').click(function(){
       $('.sidebar').toggleClass('visible'); 
    });           
});
```